# Working with dates in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am very new when it comes to using SQL and what I am attempting to do is select the waterUsage and electrcityUsage using only the month and year and select the waterUsage and electrcityUsage from the previous year.

However I cannot seem to figure out the appropriate way to use dates in order to make this work.

Table:    monthlyBill

```
1. billingDate 01-SEP-15
2. waterUsage varchar(256)
3. electrcityUsage varchar(256)
4. accountNumber varchar(256)
```

```
select electrcityUsage, waterUsage 
from monthlyBill
where accountNumber ='211' 
  and billingDate = '12-12' /*,month, year*/
```

or

```
select electrcityUsage, waterUsage 
from monthlyBill
where accountNumber ='211' 
  and billingDate = DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()); /*,previous year*/
```

Comment: what is the datatype of billingDate?

Comment: Where in the [Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find `dateadd()` or `getdate()`

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SQL Server?  The syntax is SQL Server not Oracle.

Comment: I am aware if that, I am using Oracle. I am ver new to SQL in general

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option uses `TO_CHAR`:

```
select electrcityUsage, waterUsage 
from monthlyBill
where accountNumber = '211' and
     to_char(billing_date, 'MM-YYYY') = '12-2012'
```

This assumes that you're actually using Oracle, and not SQL Server.

If you wanted `2012` and `2011` then just go ahead and add another condition to the `WHERE` clause.  I might use `EXTRACT` in this case:

```
select electrcityUsage, waterUsage 
from monthlyBill
where accountNumber = '211' and
    extract(month from billingDate) = 12 and
    extract(year from billingdate) in (2011, 2012)
```

Comment: and how would you do the exact same thing but minus one year?

Comment: Do you want the year `2011` hard coded, or do you want one year before the current year?

Comment: one year before whatever the WHERE statement would say,

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `billingdate` is a `DATE` column.

You can't compare a `DATE` with a string value. If you only want to compare "parts" of a date you need to convert the date to a string:

```
select electrcityUsage, waterUsage 
from monthlyBill
where accountNumber ='211' 
  and to_char(billingDate,'MM-YY') = '12-12'
```

But I would **strongly** recommend to **always** use four digit years:

```
select electrcityUsage, waterUsage 
from monthlyBill
where accountNumber ='211' 
  and to_char(billingDate,'MM-YYYY') = '12-2012'
```

or use the extract function:

```
select electrcityUsage, waterUsage 
from monthlyBill
where accountNumber ='211' 
  and extract(month from billingDate) = 12 
  and extract(year from billingdate) = 2012;
```

To get the previous year, subtract a year, but you need to take into account that in Oracle a `DATE` **always** contains a time as well (despite the name of the data type). To set the time to `00:00:00` use `trunc()`

```
select electrcityUsage, waterUsage 
from monthlyBill
where accountNumber ='211' 
  and trunc(billingdate) = trunc(sysdate - interval '1' year);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `BILLINGDATE` is a DATE column:

I recommend avoiding the use of the TO_CHAR or EXTRACT function in a case like this, as they're likely to force a full table scan - perhaps not an issue for small databases and tables, but perhaps very important when querying a large table. Instead I suggest getting used to using a BETWEEN comparison for handling date ranges - something similar to the following:

```
SELECT ELECTRICITYUSAGE, WATERUSAGE
  FROM MONTHLYBILL
  WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER = '211' AND
        BILLING_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-DEC-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                         AND TO_DATE('31-DEC-2012 23:59:59', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

It's important to remember that in Oracle a DATE column is actually a timestamp and so there is always a date and a time component to it (accurate only down to seconds, not milli- or micro-seconds), so you always need to take the hours/minutes/seconds into account when dealing with Oracle DATEs.

Best of luck.

Comment: I highly recommend to **not** use month names in  to_date() - the correct parsing of the names depends on the _client's_ language setting. Your query would fail on my computer.

Comment: I understand your point but respectfully disagree. 11-DEC-2013 is unambiguous. 11-12-13 is...what? Plus DD-MON-YYYY is US military format. Got used to the logic of it it 30+ years ago. Never looked back. Maybe we could standardize on the Esperanto month names? Looks like I'd need to get used to two or three differences from the English abbreviations - seems to be roughly the same for German IIRC. YM will undoubtedly V. :-)

Comment: Well as I said: `11-DEC-2013` will **fail** if run from a _client_  that spells December differently (German, Spanish, Italian, Polish and a lot more) - unambiguous or not. The problem is that this depends on the *client* not the server. It's better to use a format that writes the month as a number and if you provide a  format mask for the `to_date()` function (which you always should do anyway) it's not ambiguous. e,g. `to_date(`01-12-2012', 'dd-mm-yyyy')` I typically use international ISO format e.g. `2012-12-01` (of course **with** a format mask)